# Dragging view in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

This is a small thing, but quite annoying.

In Interface Builder, if I have a superview with subviews, and the subviews cover all the superview's area, it becomes not possible to select the superview by clicking.

The solution is to select it from the Document Outline (the list on the left). Now the next problem is: how to move the superview after selecting -- arrow keys won't work because I am in the Document Outline! Currently I just go to Size inspector (CMD + ALT + 5), and modify the superview's x & y there.

Anyone got a better method so that the arrow keys work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it: after selecting the view in Document Outline, just carefully select it on the canvas by clicking exactly on one of its edges/corners (when the cursor become sizing arrows).